# How to make React app inside Laravel to work with same css inside public folder

Tags: css, reactjs, laravel

I have Laravel app with React preset. But the html inside react component is not using css from Laravel public folder. CSS is done by another person and I want each component to use same CSS from public folder of Laravel. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to have a agnostic setup meaning maintain a separate reactjs folder and laravel as well.Therefore,use reactjs only for the frontend view and laravel for serving the request as API endpoint.

However, kindly add `<link href="--laravel css file--" />` in the index.html of reactjs

**EDIT:** Or else add it in the laravel layout app.blade.php

`<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I would have love to do both separately but frontend is designed by another person and I don't need reactjs for every page, I need reactjs for only some process. Reactjs is embedded as preset and need to work with Laravel blade too, I dont have index page for reactjs.